# "502 Bad Gatway" error after in nginx after reverse proxy of https to http

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a web server running on 8030 port and some static web files which should be accessed through 80 port. Both front-end and back-end files are on same linux machine.

The front-end receives data from back-end using REST API. I have a static IP and a domain name. DNS server is a CDN which connects https://a.b.com to my IP address, i.e. 1.2.3.4 here. My server itself has no SSL certifications.

So my front-end app is hosted on **https**://a.b.com and makes GET requests to **http**://1.2.3.4:8030/v1/getdata

This is my NGINX configuration file:

```
upstream backend {
        server 1.2.3.4:8030;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /home/user/static;

        index index.html;

        server_name https://a.b.com;

        location / {
               
                try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
        }

        location /v1 {
                proxy_pass http://backend;

        }
}
```

Static files are loaded successfully but the AJAX GET request to my application server returns "502 Bad Gateway".

How can I fix this?

Firewall rules are set and remote access using static IP is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the config file as following and now everything is OK:

```
upstream backend {
        server localhost:8030;
}

server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        index index.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {

                root /home/user/output;

                try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
        }

        location /v1 {
                proxy_pass http://backend;
        }

}
```

Thanks to [this](https://pavankjadda.medium.com/how-to-deploy-angular-and-spring-boot-apps-behind-nginx-proxy-server-fc623f36edcc)